# How to resolve "Failed to load model" error in Vertex AI for batch predictions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to run batch predictions for my custom trained model in vertex AI. The model was imported into the Model Registry from a Cloud Storage bucket. The model is stored as a "model.joblib" file with scikit-learn framework.

Since, I want to schedule batch predictions, I wrote a cloud function to do the same.

I followed this document. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/get-batch-predictions#make-batch-request). Additionally, I added the following:

```
"dedicated_resources": {
        "machine_spec": {
            "machine_type": "c2-standard-16"
        },
        "starting_replica_count":1,
        "max_replica_count":3,
```

I want to predict for about 300K users, over 47 features for a KMeans model of 7 clusters.

But I am constantly getting the following error:

1. In logging:

> ERROR:root:Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/0001/model.joblib. std::bad_alloc. (Error code: 0)

2. In Batch Prediction UI:

> Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid.

I have tried different machine types:

- c2-standard-16
- n1-highcpu-4
- n1-highcpu-16

But the error is not changing. Is this a machine_type issue or is this something else? How do I resolve this?

Edit: Cloud function for batch prediction

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1beta1
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
  project = "abc"
  display_name = "audience-segmentation-predictions"
  model_name = "projects/abc/locations/us-central1/models/19290"
  instances_format = "bigquery"
  bigquery_source_input_uri = "bq://abc.ml_final_g0_us.model_input_transformed_daily"
  predictions_format = "bigquery"
  bigquery_destination_output_uri = "bq://abc.ml_final_g0_us"
  location = "us-central1"
  api_endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"


  def create_batch_prediction_job_bigquery_sample(project,display_name,model_name,instances_format,bigquery_source_input_uri,predictions_format,bigquery_destination_output_uri,location,api_endpoint):
      # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
      client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
      # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
      # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
      client = aiplatform_v1beta1.JobServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
      model_parameters_dict = {}
      model_parameters = json_format.ParseDict(model_parameters_dict, Value())

      batch_prediction_job = {
          "display_name": display_name,
          # Format: 'projects/{project}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
          "model": model_name,
          "model_parameters": model_parameters,
          "input_config": {
              "instances_format": instances_format,
              "bigquery_source": {"input_uri": bigquery_source_input_uri},
          },
          "output_config": {
              "predictions_format": predictions_format,
              "bigquery_destination": {"output_uri": bigquery_destination_output_uri},
          },
          "instance_config": {"excluded_fields": "clientid"},
          "dedicated_resources": {
            "machine_spec": {
                "machine_type": "c2-standard-30"
            },
            
        },
      }
      parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
      response = client.create_batch_prediction_job(
          parent=parent, batch_prediction_job=batch_prediction_job
      )
      print("response:", response)

  create_batch_prediction_job_bigquery_sample(project,display_name,model_name,instances_format,bigquery_source_input_uri,predictions_format,bigquery_destination_output_uri,location,api_endpoint)
```

Comment: Can you share your cloud function code?

Comment: Could you confirm that this model and container have been used before without issues? Also it would be helpful if you could provide full stacktrace of container logs.

Comment: I have now added the cloud function @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @SakshiGatyan, the model works properly locally. this is the first time i am testing it on GCP and failing to get the results.

Comment: Agree with @SakshiGatyan, your model seams not well loaded. Something could be wrong in the packaginf

Comment: How do i resolve that?